# How to add an indext which compares now() with some parameters postgres

Tags: postgresql, indexing

How is it possible to write an index which compares the current time with valid_from and valid_to. The idea is to only be able to create a promo_code if the time now() is not between valid_from and valid_to. Is this possible?

```
create index idx_allow_same_codes_if_expired on promo_code(code) 
 where now() NOT between valid_from and valid_to ;
```

this does not work though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have an index for that, and an index doesn't make sense here.

But you can create a check constraint:

```
alter table promo_code
   add check (valid_from > now() OR valid_to < now());
```